# ssh - erro ao se conectar com 4linux

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

Estou com um probleminha na questão do ssh, sou iniciante no linux e estou fazendo um curso na 4linux sobre o básico de Linux e etc...
Estou na parte de conectar em cloud via ssh. Quando eu fiz pela primeira vez deu certo, menos a senha, mais ai acho que já seria com eles, o que acontece na verdade agora é que quando digito isso não carrega nada, fica só nessa linha o terminal com o cursor lá congelado, como se estivesse esperando finalizar algum processo, só que não acontece nada, isso ocorria também com o github quando eu clonava os repositórios via ssh, mudei pra https por conta disso.

**Exemplo:**

> `ssh -l <login> cloud.4linux.com.br`

(o cursor fica parado e nada acontece)

**obs1**: Antes, a primeira vez deu certo, pediu até uma confirmação, criou o arquivo (known_hosts), dai apaguei, agora criei pra ver se resolvia, mas não resolveu, esta em branco e quando apago e rodo o comando ele não cria de volta.

**obs2**: Depois de um bom tempo aparece: `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out`.

Comment: O erro `connection timed out` ocorre quando o servidor esta fora do ar. Tem certeza que o serviço deles esta no ar?

Comment: Confere se a porta é a 22 mesmo, talvez seja outra, entao precisará especifica-la.

Comment: Vou verificar se o servidor esta no ar e também a questão da porta e trago o resultado pra vocês.

Comment: Aparentemente agora esta tudo ok. Não sei se o server estava off antes, ou se foi algum erro. Mas agora ta conectando.

Comment: Só esta dando esse erro: - "Error response from daemon: No such container: 37709
Error: failed to start containers: 37709
Error: No such container: 37709
Error response from daemon: No such container: 37709
Connection to cloud.4linux.com.br closed."